# Uniqueness of solution to Helmholtz-style equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

> Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, bounded and connected with $C^1$ boundary. Suppose $q\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ and that $q\geq C>0$ almost everywhere. Consider the following PDE problem:
>   $$-\nabla\cdot(\nabla u) + qu = 0\quad\text{in }\Omega$$
>   and with zero boundary condition, i.e. $u|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$.
>
> Show that there exists a unique $u\in L^2(\Omega)$ solving the problem.

I've been given a hint that I can use a calculus of variation approach and formulate a minimization problem. For example I know that the PDE
$$-\nabla\cdot(\nabla u) = f$$

can be written in weak formulation as $a(u,v) = \ell(v)$ with

$$a(u,v) := \int_\Omega \nabla u\cdot \nabla v\,\mathrm{d}x\quad\quad\text{and   }\quad\quad \ell(v) := \int_\Omega fv\,\mathrm{d}x$$
where $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ is a test function.

For this problem I know that the uniqueness of the solution arises from Lax-Milgram theorem or equivalently from the minimization problem
$$\min\limits_{v\in H_0^1(\Omega)}\left\{\frac12 a(v,v) - \ell(v)\right\}. $$
I believe I have to formulate a similar minimization problem and prove there exists a unique minimizer. However, if I do the usual approach my $\ell$ will depend on $u$ which is not good, right? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Maybe u should use Fredholm alternative.

Comment: @Yongyong Do you have a hint how? I don't really see it.

Comment: You can try to apply the technique in Evans' PDE book, see 6.2.3 in the book. The example there is not a function $q$ but a constant $\lambda$, i.e. $\lambda u$ on the r.h.s., but I think they should be similar.

Comment: @Yongyong Thanks a lot. I'll give it a go.

Comment: or precisely 6.5, the chapter of eigenfunctions of compact operator.